# Why won't my new Ruby on Rails site start in development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, webrick

I'm using user-per-app configuration on an Ubuntu server running ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.8.

When I create a new site using `rails new test_app` in the home directory of one user (my main user) and then run `rails s` from the app directory I get

```
Rails 3.2.8 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
```

but when I `su` to another user and run the same commands in the home directory of that user, I get

```
Rails 3.2.8 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
```

and the same thing even if I run

```
rails s -e development
```

No matter what I do as the other user, I cannot get WEBrick to start in development. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must be my day to post Stack Exchange questions and then [find the answer myself](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204670/why-arent-my-bash-aliases-applied-when-logging-in-to-server) within moments.

Obviously there was something different about these two users and I just could not figure out what it was. The difference between users ended up being that as the failing user I was playing around with @wayne-e-seguin 's [SM framework](https://smf.sh/). The default installation of this sets the `environment` and `RAILS_ENV` to production. Setting those to "development" in `~/.smrc` did the trick.